# Thread not returning after notifyall()

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to multithreading with Java. I've done some research, read tutorials, and done tests, but I'm stuck with this problem. Basically, I'm setting up the skeleton of a game, and I'd like to have the main activity class, a thread class which contains methods, perform slow operations (reading files and unpacking contents to buffers), and have a thread which is the game loop react to UI operations.

First, I have the main activity class which instantiates and starts a separate thread:

```java
public class ExperimentsActivity extends Activity {

// This is just a container class with some member data such as ByteBuffers and arrays
TestClass tclass = new TestClass(this);

// Main looping thread
MainLoopThread loop;
Thread mainLoop;

// Start the main looping thread which will trigger the engine's operations
loop = new MainLoopThread(tclass);
mainLoop = new Thread(loop);
mainLoop.start();
loop.setRunning(true);

(...)
}
```

Then, I have the `MainLoopThread` class which implements the thread for the game logic:

```java
public class MainLoopThread implements Runnable  {

public boolean running;
private TestClass baseData;

// Thread for data loading/unpacking ( CLASS DEFINITION BELOW )
GFXUnpack dataUnpack;
Thread dataUnpackThread;

public MainLoopThread( TestClass testClassStructure ) {
    running = false;
    baseData = testClassStructure;
}

public void setRunning ( boolean run ) {
    if ( run == true )
    {
        // Launch the thread which manages loading and unpacking graphics
        dataUnpack = new GFXUnpack(baseData.filepack[0]);
        dataUnpackThread = new Thread(dataUnpack);
        dataUnpackThread.start();
        dataUnpack.setRunning(true);
        fileOpened = false;

        // Open the GFX packet file
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                dataUnpack.setOperation(2);                     
                Log.d("MainLoopThread", "File opening : waiting...");
                while ( dataUnpack.fileOpened == false ) {
                    wait();
                }
                Log.d("MainLoopThread", "File opening wait completed");
            }

            if ( dataUnpack.outCode == -1 ) 
                    Log.d("MainLoopThread", "File opening error !!");
                else fileOpened = true;
                    Log.d("MainLoopThread", "File opening completed");
            } 
            catch ( Exception exp ) {
                Log.d("MainLoopThread", "File opening code exception !!" + exp);
            }
        }
        else if ( dataUnpack.running == true ) dataUnpack.setRunning(false);              running = run;
    }

    // ------------------------------------
    // Here is the main looping thread. All the events related to loading 
    // and unpacking graphics go here
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            synchronized (this) {
              // ------ Read a GFX packet and update texture pixels
              if ( fileOpened == true ) {
                  try {
                      // ( Do some stuff... )
                      wait();
                  } catch ( Exception exp ) {
                  Log.d("MainLoopThread", "Exception thrown !! " + exp );
              }
          }
      } // ( Thread-out code removed. Anyway, it never passed here )
  }
```

And finally, the `GFXUnpack` thread class, which contains the code which open the file on SD card,
reads stuff in it and writes to buffers:

```java
public class GFXUnpack implements Runnable {
// -------------    
public boolean running = false;
private Filedata fdata;
private int operation = 0, parameter = 0;
public boolean fileOpened;
public int outCode;  // Used to signal the caller about the outcome of the operation
// ------------------------------
public GFXUnpack ( Filedata packetDataStructure ) {
    this.fdata = packetDataStructure;
}
// --------
public void setRunning ( boolean run ) {
    running = run;   operation = 0;  fileOpened = false;            
    outCode = 0;      parameter = 0;
}
// --------
public void setOperation ( int op ) {
    operation = op;
}
// ---
public void setOperation ( int op, int parm ) {
    operation = op;
    parameter = parm;
}
// ---------    
public synchronized void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
      switch ( operation ) {
                case ( 2 ) :  // Open the gfx data file
                        ( ...do stuff... )
                        break;                  
                    }
                    // ---------
                    try {
                           ( ...Do some stuff here... )
                           Log.d("GFXUnpack", "Mapping file");
                           ( ...Do some stuff here... )
                           Log.d("GFXUnpack", "Mapped file");
                           fileOpened = true;
                           outCode = 1;
                    } catch ( Exception e ) {
                        Log.d("GFXUnpack", "File opening exception !! " + e);
                        outCode = -1;
                    }
                    finally {
                        operation = 0;       parameter = 0;
                        notifyAll();
                        Log.d("GFXUnpack", "Notified file opening");
                    }
                }
                break;
    // ----------------
            }
            // ----- Other cases here... 
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above, the debugger output is:

> MainLoopThread       File opening : waiting...
>     GFXUnpack            Mapping file
>      GFXUnpack            Mapped file
>      GFXUnpack            Notified file opening

Then, the app hangs and I have to force close it. I thought, since I call `notifyAll()` in the `run()` method of `GFXunpack` (in the `finally{}` block), that the caller thread (MainLoopThread) would proceed and I would see the debugger message 'File opening completed', but the app hangs instead.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MainLoopThread` instance waits on `this` (an instance of `MainLoopThread`), and the `GFXUnpack` instance notifies on `this` (an instance of `GFXUnpack`). So the notifier doesn't notify the waiting thread.

The two objects must use the **same object instance** to wait and notify. And even better, you should use higher-level abstractions from the `java.util.concurrent` package, like Semaphores, CountDownLatches, etc., rather than these hard to use low-level methods.

Moreover, `wait()` should always be called in a loop that checks if the condition necessary to wake up is realized and starts waiting again if it's not, due to spurious wakeups.

Comment: Thank you JB, i will do some research and testing about the direction you gave to me !!